# How to define generic function rejecting key from object in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

I'm trying to define a utility function to clean up objects of specific keys.

```
/**
 * Strip all the __typenames from the payload.
 */
interface WithTypename {
  __typename?: string;
};

type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

const omitTypename = <T extends WithTypename>({ __typename, ...rest }: T): Omit<T, '__typename'> => ({ ...rest });
```

But compiler complains on the function parameters that `{ __typename, ...rest }`. *Rest types may only be created from object types.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known limitation of spread in Typescript, there are multiple issues on it [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26412) is a recent one.

One possible workaround is to use `Object.assign` and then delete the extra property.

```
/**
 * Strip all the __typenames from the payload.
 */
interface WithTypename {
__typename?: string;
};

type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

const omitTypename = <T extends WithTypename>(o: T): Omit<T, '__typename'> => {
    let r = Object.assign({}, o);
    delete r.__typename;
    return r;
}
```